# python RE white space in the pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a Python script to find a tag name in a string like this:

`string='Tag Name =LIC100 State =TRUE'`

If a use a expression like this

`re.search('Name(.*)State',string)`

I get " =LIC100". I would like to get just LIC100.

Any suggestions on how to set up the pattern to eliminate the whitespace and the equal signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the tips above, I manage to find a nice solution.
Actually, the string I am trying to process has some non-printable characters. It is like this

```
"Tag Name\x00=LIC100\x00\tState=TRUE"
```

Using the concept of lookahead and lookbehind I found the following solution:

```
import re
s = 'Tag Name\x00=LIC100\x00\tState=TRUE'
T=re.search(r'(?<=Name\x00=)(.*)(?=\x00\tState)',s)
print(T.group(0))
```

The nice thing about this is that the outcome does not have any non-printable character on it.

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(10, 16), match='LIC100'>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you get 0+ chars other than line break chars from `Name` up to the last `State`. You may restrict the pattern in Group 1 to just non-whitespaces:

```
import re
string='Tag Name =LIC100 State =TRUE'
m = re.search(r'Name\s*=(\S*)',string)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/PEeV8y)

**Pattern details**:

- `Name` - a literal char sequence
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `=` - a literal `=`
- `(\S*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than whitespace (or `\S+` can be used to match 1 or more chars other than whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would probably just be to strip it out after the fact, like so:

```
s = " =LIC100 "
s = s.strip('= ')
print(s)
#LIC100
```

If you insist on doing it within the regex, you can try something like:

```
reg = r'Name[ =]+([A-Za-z0-9]+)\s+State'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex is failing because `(.*)` captures all characters until the occurance of `State`. Instead of capturing everything, you can use a **positive lookbehind** to describe what *preceeds*, but is not included in, the content you actually want to capture. In this case, "Name =" preceeds the match, so we can stick it in the lookbehind assertion as `(?<=Name =)`, then proceed to capture everything until the next whitespace:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Tag Name =LIC100 State =TRUE'
>>> r = re.compile("(?<=Name =)\w*")
>>> print(r.search(s))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(10, 16), match='LIC100'>
>>> print(r.search(s).group(0))
LIC100
```

Comment: Thanks skrrgwasme. This help me a lot.

Comment: I realized that the string that I am processing has some no-printable characters. The string is like 'Tag Name\x00=LIC100\x00\tState=TRUE'. I tryed to use "T=re.search(r'(?<=Name\x00=)\x00*',s)" but it returns <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(10, 10), match=''>